# Converting Matlab arrays to LaTeX compatible Code with special format

Tags: conversion, matlab

I have a Matlab array of dimension 40X12. The array is a little bit special. All the odd row is expressed as scientific expression, while the even row is not. For example, the first row can be [3.5e-4,7.5e-4,2.3e-4,...,9e-4] while the second row is [0.1,0.2,0.3,...,0.4]. I want to make a latex table such that in latex, all the odd row give scientific notation expression but all the even row does not. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is much easier to help you if we have some working code to start from.

Comment: You can print to a file from matlab (with for example fprintf) and then use [pgfplotstable](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) to create the table. This has the additional advantage that you don't have to copy-paste the arrays into latex again after you update the matlab code.